# nameerror: name 'x_value' is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

I started python coding recently to complete some of my project tasks. I was trying to collect data from sensors and plot it in real-time. I am doing it using two separate codes. The data acquisition code is okay but the plotting code is not working.

Data acquisition code:

```
from  datetime import datetime
import time
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import csv

fieldnames = ["x_value", "D_1", "D_2", "D_3", "D_4", "D_5", "D_6"]

spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
mcp = MCP.MCP3008 (spi, cs)
print('x_value, D_1, D_2, D_3, D_4, D_5, D_6')
print('-' * 67)
while True:
try:
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        values[i] = mcp.read(i)

    d=datetime.now()

    values[0] = round(((-25.74257)*(values[0]*0.00488758553))+65)
    values[1] = round(((-25.74257)*(values[1]*0.00488758553))+65)
    values[2] = round(((-25.74257)*(values[2]*0.00488758553))+65)
    values[3] = round(((-25.74257)*(values[3]*0.00488758553))+65)
    values[4] = round(((-25.74257)*(values[4]*0.00488758553))+65)
    values[5] = round(((-25.74257)*(values[5]*0.00488758553))+65)
    # Print the ADC values.
    print('{:%M.%S}, {:>4},  {:>4},  {:>4},  {:>4},   {:>4},   {:>4}'.format(d, values[0], values[1],values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5]))
    str1='{:%M.%S}, {:>4},  {:>4},  {:>4},  {:>4},   {:>4},   {:>4}\n'.format(d, values[0], values[1],values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5])
    fout=open('data.csv', 'at')
    fout.writelines(str1)
    fout.close()
except RuntimeError as error:
    print('failed')
time.sleep(1.0)
```

Graph code

```
import csv
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()
def animate(i):
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = data['x_value']
y1 = data['D_1']
y2 = data['D_2']
y3 = data['D_3']
y4 = data['D_4']
y5 = data['D_5']
y6 = data['D_6']

plt.cla()

plt.plot(x, y1, label='Sensor 1')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='Sensor 2')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='Sensor 3')
plt.plot(x, y4, label='Sensor 4')
plt.plot(x, y5, label='Sensor 5')
plt.plot(x, y6, label='Sensor 6')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1.0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run Graph_plot3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'x_value'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 215, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 999, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1740, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1762, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "/home/pi/Graph_plot3.py", line 17, in animate
    x = data['x_value']
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2491, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'x_value'
```

Would anyone please help me to solve the problem? This is my first question here, and I apologize for my weak English.

Comment: `KeyError: 'x_value'` generally means that something you're indexing with that key does not actually look how you want it to look. In your case that's probably the line `x = data['x_value']`. Can you print out `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`? Does it look how you want it to look?

Comment: Thank you Klaus D. I solved this problem by myself....